# Is this a mnemoniac to binary?

Tags: numbers

What do numbers like 0x00000000 and similar do?

Comment: more details or it will probably get closed.

Comment: Erm... you mean [Mnemonic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mnemonic)?

Answer (score 1):

The "0x" prefix indicates that the rest of the number is to be interpreted in base 16 (hexadecimal), with A through F serving as the digits with values 11 through 15.  "0x00000000" is just a number composed of all zeroes, and so, as in every base, it is equal to 0.

Answer (score 1):

The `0x` simply means that the following digits are in [hexadecimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) (base 16).

Beyond that, your question is somewhat meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

It's zero in hexadecimal format.
Many programming languages accept such values as integers.